# How to return 0 for record count when nothing returns for that hour using datepart?

Tags: sql-server

In my sample query below, I am pulling the count by hour correctly, but I need it to return all hours of the day and display 0 for the hours that have no data. Is there an easy way for me to do this?

Here is my SQL:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp;

CREATE TABLE #Temp (TempNumber NVARCHAR(50),TempDateTime DATETIME2)

INSERT INTO #Temp (TempNumber, TempDateTime) 
VALUES ('11287233600','2019-08-20 08:27:08.047')

INSERT INTO #Temp (TempNumber, TempDateTime) 
VALUES ('11287233601','2019-08-20 08:32:08.047')

INSERT INTO #Temp (TempNumber, TempDateTime) 
VALUES ('11287233602','2019-08-20 10:27:08.047')

INSERT INTO #Temp (TempNumber, TempDateTime) 
VALUES ('11287233603','2019-08-20 12:27:08.047')

INSERT INTO #Temp (TempNumber, TempDateTime) 
VALUES ('11287233604','2019-08-20 16:27:08.047')

INSERT INTO #Temp (TempNumber, TempDateTime) 
VALUES ('11287233605','2019-08-20 23:27:08.047')

SELECT DATEPART(hh,TempDateTime) AS TempDatePart,
COUNT(DISTINCT TempNumber) AS RecordCount
FROM #Temp
GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, TempDateTime)
```

[image]

Here is what I'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: _Please_ type out `hour` instead of `hh` shorthand. [Here's why](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations).

Answer (score 5):

You can use a table constructor of all hours (0-23) and join to that from your `DATEPART` function.

**[DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=012ea714e11fa9d2656ec37cc8f6080d)**

```
SELECT 
   h.h as DatePartHour, 
   --DATEPART(hour,TempDateTime) AS TempDatePart,
   COUNT(DISTINCT TempNumber) AS RecordCount
FROM #Temp
   full join (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(0)) h(h)
   on h.h = DATEPART(hour,TempDateTime)
GROUP BY  h.h
```